# Failed to compile src\App.js Line 66:12: 'oldstate' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, undefined

Code of 'App.js'

There are several other different files, so if anyone needs to see the file structure please let me know.

```
import React from 'react';
import CoinList from './components/CoinList/CoinList';
import AccountBalance from './components/AccountBalance/AccountBalance';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ExchangeHeader from './components/ExchangeHeader/ExchangeHeader';

const Div = styled.div`
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #373c46;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.842);
`;

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleRefresh = this.handleRefresh.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            balance: 10000,
            showBalance: true,
            coinData: [
                {
                    name: 'Bitcoin',
                    ticker: 'BTC',
                    balance: 1.5,
                    price: 9999.99
                },
                {
                    name: 'Ethereum',
                    ticker: 'ETH',
                    balance: 32.0,
                    price: 299.99
                },
                {
                    name: 'Tether',
                    ticker: 'USDT',
                    balance: 0,
                    price: 1.0
                },
                {
                    name: 'Ripple',
                    ticker: 'XRP',
                    balance: 1000,
                    price: 0.2
                },
                {
                    name: 'Bitcoin Cash',
                    ticker: 'BCH',
                    balance: 10,
                    price: 298.99
                },
                {
                    name: 'Cardano',
                    ticker: 'ADA',
                    balance: 20,
                    price: 1.56
                },
            ]
        }
        this.handleRefresh = this.handleRefresh.bind(this);
        this.handleBalanceVisibilityChange = this.handleBalanceVisibilityChange.bind(this);

    };

    handleBalanceVisibilityChange() {
        this.setState(function (oldState) {
            return {
                ...oldstate,
                showBalance: !oldState.showBalance
            }
        });
    }

    handleRefresh(valueChangeTicker) {
        const newCoinData = this.state.coinData.map(
            function ({ticker, name, price}) {
                let newPrice = price
                if (valueChangeTicker === ticker) {

                    const randomPercentage = 0.995 + Math.random() * 0.01
                    newPrice = newPrice * randomPercentage
                }
                return {
                    name,
                    ticker,
                    price: newPrice
                }
            });
        this.setState({coinData: newCoinData});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Div className="App">
                <ExchangeHeader/>
                <AccountBalance
                    amount={this.state.balance}
                    showBalance={this.state.showBalance}
                    handleBalanceVisibilityChange={this.handleBalanceVisibilityChange}/>
                <CoinList
                    coinData={this.state.coinData}
                    showBalance={this.state.showBalance}
                    handleRefresh={this.handleRefresh}/>
            </Div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

I'm unsure what to do to fix this error. I'm following a course to learn React, and it was made several years ago, so I *think* that it might have something to do with an update.

I've also tried several solutions but came up with the same issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: And this is why you want to always stick with the language conventions around capitalisation. Variables in JS use camelCase with an initial lowercase, so if you're getting an error about `oldstate`, that should immediately make you go "wait, why is that a lowercase s instead of a capital letter S?". Also, it's why you want to make sure to install an extension to whatever code editor you're using that can flag lexical errors like this: `oldstate` is a nonexistent variable, your editor should have flagged an error for it before you tried to compile anything.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I can't believe I missed that. I'll be sure to look into that.